# Компиляция sass документа при перезагрузке страницы

Tags: sass, scss

Я создал функцию, которая генерирует случайный цвет. Но возникла проблема - она не работает при перезагрузке страницы. Как мне сделать так, чтобы scss файл компилировался каждую перезагрузку? Можно на любой технологии.

Comment: Можно присвоить всем элементам, которые изменяют цвет, какой-нибудь атрибут. А потом по селектору с атрибутом найти их и через функцию-генератор вставить этот случайный цвет.

Comment: используй клиентскую компиляцию, например с помощью: [sass.js](https://github.com/medialize/sass.js/)

Comment: @Grundy, ответы в ответы.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а комментарии в комментарии :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

P.S. Изменения ответа за 23.10.2017   Я тут расхваливал webpack и даже за конкурсный вопрос 100 балов получил, но есть проблема, в той конструкции которую я привел, less отказывается читать `background-image: url(путь к картинке) ;` путь должен быть обязательно в одинарных кавычках, но используя новый приведенный пример файла webpack.config.js, там все исправлено. В комментах  есть объяснения что к чему.

Предлагаю webpack, ниже привожу полную структуру. Не обязательно что-бы сервер был именно nodejs, но именно для webpack, nodejs  должен присутствовать...

Файл в корне webpack.config.js.  в примере ниже используется less, но нет абсолютно ни какой разницы, просто замените less на sass и естественно пакеты установки не less, а sass. Работоспособность проверена полностью, один минус, не показывает ошибки, надо быть внимательнее, когда пишите код на sass компилирует даже с ошибками. Можно просто создавать сотню файлов sass и все они будут прописываться в один css файл, лично для меня это удобно, подключаешь один css и все работает. Куда какие файлы прописать увидите в комментариях в файле  webpack.config.js
**И еще забыл добавить, для того чтобы все файлы sass или less  компилировались надо их импортировать в главный less или sass !!!**

```
       var path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./less/main.less", // путь откуда берет less
    node: {
        fs: 'empty',
        net: 'empty'
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/public/css", // путь куда вставлять компилированный css 
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: "style-loader",
                    use: ["css-loader", "less-loader"]
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|svg|gif)$/,
                include: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, './img/')  // а тут надо прописать имя папки откуда будет брать все картинки
                ],
                use: [{
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: './public/img/[hash].[ext]', 
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2|png|jpg|jpeg|svg|gif)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader'
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: 'main.css' // а тут надо прописать имя css которое вы хотите 
        })
    ]
};
```

Далее привожу пример файл package.json там найдете команды запуска именно webpack, и увидите, что установить

```
       {
  "name": "********",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "***********************",
  "main": "serv.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node serv",
    "watch": "webpack -w --config webpack.config.js"/*команда запуска webpack  npm rum watch*/
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "**********************************"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "short",
    "advertising",
    "site"
  ],
  "author": "***************",
  "license": "ISC",
  "homepage": "*******************",
  "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
"css-loader": "^0.28.7",
"express": "^4.16.1",
"fs": "0.0.1-security",
"mongoose": "^4.12.1",
"style-loader": "^0.19.0",
"url-loader": "^0.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1",
"file-loader": "^1.1.5",
"less": "^2.7.2",
"less-loader": "^4.0.5",
"webpack": "^3.6.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Если не сложно попробуйте так с scss, времени нет, если все удачно то приму)

Comment: На вкус и цвет... Как известно...  Лично мне удобно))))

Comment: @Duoxx, посмотри изменения в ответе, там были проблемы  с url  в background... не читал путь

Answer (score 1):

Вместо того, чтобы компилировать scss в статический css, надо выполнять компиляцию либо сервером, отдающим css-файл, либо непосредвственно на клиенте.

Answer (score 1):

Можете использовать [`browser-sync`](https://browsersync.io/). В одной консоли запускаете сборщик sass в режиме watch:

```
sass -w
```

В другой запускаете `browser-sync`:

```
browser-sync start --server --files "*.css"
```

В этом случае каждый раз после сборки готового css он будет отдаваться сразу без перезагрузки страницы.

Comment: 1. Как это должно помочь? 2. На продакшене сервер с browser-sync'ом? 3. Даже если да, то а смысл?

Comment: @Qwertiy в вопросе ничего не сказано про контекст. Помочь это должно самым явным образом, эта связка делает именно то, что сказал автор. Естественно, на прод такое нельзя класть, это dev среда.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю вопрос, он хочет, чтобы на проде при каждом обновлении страницы генерировался новый случайный цвет. Ну даже если dev, ведь в решении с watch случайный цвет будет меняться при любом изменении исходников, а не при обновлении страницы. Поэтому этот ответ у меня вообще с вопросом не матчится...

Comment: @Qwertiy Слушайте, да. Возможно вы правы. Но это такая нестандартная задача, что смутила меня. Но я уточню, про прод он ничего не сказал. Допускаю, что автор не правильно сформулировал вопрос и то, что он хочет. Мне показалось, что у него проблема в том, что он изменяет сорцы, а при перезагрузке страницы ничего не меняется. А не меняется за счёт того, что браузер кэширует стили. И моё решение помогает обойти кэш.

Comment: @Qwertiy В таким случае решение на js подойдёт больше, вместо клиентской компиляции, т.к. пересборка сорцов на каждое обновление, это, мягко говоря, неоптимально.

Comment: В принципе, да. Но если у него есть переменная с рандомным значением и она размазана по всем стилям, то проще на клиенте скомпилировать scss, чем с нуля переписывать на js все места, где она используется. Ну и ещё можно подумать про css-переменные, но тут вопрос поддержки браузеров, плюс, насколько к ней применяются scss'ные возможности (например, осветление).

Answer (score 0):

> Как мне сделать так, чтобы scss файл компилировался каждую перезагрузку?

В подобных вопросах я совсем новичок. Похожим вопросом я занялся буквально пару дней назад. Бегло посмотрел инструментарий в сети. Нашел для себя хорошее решение - [Koala](http://koala-app.com/). Собственно его и рекомендую. Программа работает с Sass, Less и CoffeeScript. Имеет собственный самодостаточный инструментарий, хотя и позволяет подключать внешние компиляторы. На ваш выбор. Может работать в режиме активного мониторинга - запускает перекомпиляцию как только обнаружит изменение scss-файла. Бесплатна.

Использовать крайне просто. Как пример. Создаем каталог проекта. В нем создаем два подкаталога css и sass. В подкаталоге sass создаем файл styles.scss и **каталог проекта** добавляем в Koala, в настройках включаем активный мониторинг (по умолчанию он вроде включен). Результирующий файл styles.css будет лежать в подкаталоге css. При каждой перезаписи styles.scss будет происходить его фоновая перекомпиляция.

**Одно важное предупреждение**

На момент написания данного ответа последняя версия данной программы - 2.2.0. И ее не следует использовать! На фоне множества улучшений имеет существенный неисправленный баг при работе с UTF-8. Поэтому нужно использовать предыдущую версию 2.1.4, ссылку можно найти на [этой страничке](https://github.com/oklai/koala/blob/master/Changelog.md).

**По поводу использования в продакшене**

В этом случае я бы не использовал описанную выше программу на сервере, а использовал бы обычный sass-компилятор. В случае нагрузки, параллельных запросов, думаю, имеет смысл создать и свой параллелизм обработки. Некий процесс должен поддерживать "пул" сгенерированных стилей (пополнять новыми, удалять уже отданные). А основной процесс должен мочь с этим "пулом" работать.

Дабы не нарваться на кэширование, основной процесс должен отдавать странички с указанием версии [файла стилей](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671168/why-adding-version-number-to-css-file-path). Как-то так.