# Как подключить less к проекту?

Tags: node.js, css3, less, препроцессор

Подключил и установил `less` на `nodeJS` .Как подключить `less` если 2 файла для компиляции и стилей работают только в корневой папке `nodeJS`? Или теперь надо все файлы для сайта переносить в папку где `less`?

Comment: А как вы компилируете less-файлы? Вызываете через консоль или в скриптах у package.json прописали команду? Предлагаю воспользоваться каким-нибудь task-runner'ом, например, gulp. Просто напишете скрипт, где укажете в gulp.src массив путей откуда брать less-файлы, потом компилируете и укажете папку куда.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Компиляция sass документа при перезагрузке страницы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/726325/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-sass-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:

```
var gulp = require( 'gulp' );
var less = require('gulp-less');
var path = require('path');

gulp.task('less', function () {
  return
    gulp.src('./src/**/*.less' ) // ищу все файлы с расширением .less ниже директории src
      .pipe( less() ) // компилирую
      .pipe( gulp.dest('./src/public/css') ); // вывожу в нужную папку, структура папок сохраняется
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно при желании схлопнуть в одну выходную папку без сохранения структуры директорий

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или объединить их в один файл

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]