# Webpack не загружает изображения в стилях

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, webpack

Проблема с подключением изображений в Webpack. Недавно начал изучать этот сборщик.
Вот мой код webpack.config.js:

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: "./src/index.jsx",
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public',
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: '/public/'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js|.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.sass$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css-loader!sass-loader?sourceMap')
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: 'app.css', allChunks: true })
  ],
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  }
};
```

Когда запускаю его с подключением какойто картинки на background в sass то в консоли выдает ошибки например эту

```
 ERROR in ./src/img/ICON.png
    Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
    (Source code omitted for this binary file)
     @ ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?sourceMap!./src/sass/main.sass 6:140536-140562
```

Вопрос: какой loader мне нужно подлючить чтобы загружались и компилились картинки в стилях?

Спасибо!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/726325/Компиляция-sass-документа-при-перезагрузке-страницы/729312#729312  посмотри тут все работает 100%%%  вот щас сам этой сборкой работаю